# How can I add class active when a link clicked and redirect?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

My vue component is like this:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        ...
        <div class="list-group">
            <a :href="baseUrl+'/message/inbox'" class="list-group-item">
                Message
            </a>
            <a :href="baseUrl+'/message/review'" class="list-group-item">
                Review
            </a>
            <a :href="baseUrl+'/message/resolution'" class="list-group-item">
                Resolution
            </a>
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        ...
        data() {
            return {
                baseUrl: window.Laravel.baseUrl
            }
        },
        ...
    }
</script>
```

When the link is clicked, it will call the url, I want to add class active on the clicked link after reloading the page.

But, I'm still confused, How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a computed property, say, `currentPath`:

```
computed: {
  currentPath () {
    // grab current url and return the part after `baseUrl `
    // e.g. '/message/inbox' or '/message/review'
    return '/message/inbox'
  }
}
```

And a CSS class for your special style:

```
.active-item {
  /* key-value pairs here */
}
```

Then in your template, you could apply the class to the matched item:

```
<a :href="baseUrl+'/message/inbox'"
   :class="{ 'active-item': currentPath === '/message/inbox'}">
   class="list-group-item">Message</a>
<a :href="baseUrl+'/message/review'"
   :class="{ 'active-item': currentPath === '/message/review'}">
   class="list-group-item">Review</a>
```

Please read the doc on [binding HTML classes with object syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax)

Comment: Besides I have a link: `/message/inbox`, I also have a link: `/message/inbox/detail`. So the links that has the same menu, the menu is message menu. How to order the message menu is active when `/message/inbox` or `/message/inbox/detail` clicked

Comment: `/message/inbox` and `/message/inbox/detail` is a specific case. I could simply go with something like `currentPath.indexOf('/message/inbox') === 0` or so. However, if it's not as simple as that straight, then you might need to make one thing clear: what is the definition of **active** in your context? You should be able to answer it in abstract, not by specific cases. That's the way to your strategy and solution.

Comment: In other words, your code/algorithm should be able to solve a group of problems (path matching here), rather than case by case. And the key here, is to describe the commonness of those problems, not every single case.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Leo's answer, it's a good idea to introduce a component which will auto detect is active or not, so you don't need to write a bunch of `<a>` elements and many duplicate attributes.

For example a `<custom-link>` component:

```
<custom-link href="/message/inbox" class="list-group-item">
  Message
</custom-link>
<custom-link href="/message/review" class="list-group-item">
  Review
</custom-link>
<custom-link href="/message/resolution" class="list-group-item">
  Resolution
</custom-link>
```

If you don't need to reuse this component in other components or the `list-group-item` class is always necessary, you can also encapsulate this class to the `<custom-link>`. It will look even cleaner:

```
<custom-link href="/message/inbox">Message</custom-link>
<custom-link href="/message/review">Review</custom-link>
<custom-link href="/message/resolution">Resolution</custom-link>
```

the code of `custom-link` looks like:

```
<a
  :href="baseUrl + href"
  :class="{ active: isActive }"
  class="list-group-item"
>
  <slot></slot>
</a>

{
  props: ['href'],
  data: () => ({ baseUrl: window.Laravel.baseUrl }),
  computed: {
    isActive () {
      return location.href === this.baseUrl + this.href
    }
  }
}
```

I use `location.href` here directly, you can also use a computed property like Leo's example if you need some computations to get the current URL.